# Does ArcGIS Server 10.7.x always provide/support both Python 2.7 and 3.6, or sometimes the 2.7 one only?

Tags: python, arcgis-server

Reading this [ESRI support information](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013224) from the Internet (select *English* language at the bottom of the page, other translations aren't always updated), it's not clear to me if a `10.7.x` version of `ArcGIS Server` always comes with both `2.7` and `3.6` versions of `Python` language, or may sometimes come with the `2.7`version only.

Is an `ArcGIS Server` component the same whether it is linked to an `ArcGIS Desktop` installation or an `ArcGIS Pro` one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the linked article (emphasis mine):

> The ArcGIS Server component of ArcGIS Enterprise also ships with Python. In recent releases, **both** Python 2.x and Python 3.x runtimes are provided.

Below that, it is specified that versions 10.6 and higher come with Python 3.6.x and 2.7.x. I see no indication that 3.6 is *not* included in any 10.7 version.

ArcGIS Server is in no way 'linked' to either ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro (it's a separate installation), so the answer to the second part of your question would be *Yes*.

Comment: Technically, if you install Desktop first, and then the 64-bit Background Geoprocessing extension, if you then install Server, it will skip installation of 64-bit 2.7.x Python, so there is a tenuous linkage, but not in the meaning of the OP.

Comment: Note that the ArcGIS Server's _3.x_ version of Python will be sort of "buried" deep in the install directory. You don't see it get dropped down at the typical `C:\PythonXX` path when installing ArcMap (Python 2.7)